Identify a foreign (Chinese) movie dealing with a ruined father-son relationship because of a forced abortion on the son's girlfriend
Sometime around 5-6 years ago, I stumbled upon a foreign Chinese real life movie. It was essentially about the life and relationship of a boy and his father (and his mother to a lesser extent) growing up somewhere in china. 
The father and son have a good relationship at the beginning of the movie. Essentially the main plot point was about the son getting his girlfriend?, who was built up as a main character for the first half of the movie, pregnant sometime in high school on a rainy day, and the girlfriend going to the parents without telling the boyfriend who forced her to get an abortion without him knowing. As a result the girlfriend breaks up with the son I think? or somehow they stop talking to each other after this and she's never seen again, and the son doesn't understand why because he didn't know about the abortion.
The second half of the movie deals with the son know who's grown up and become an artist and is now with another woman separate from his high school girlfriend and the struggles he deals with in this new relationship, and with his parents who I guess he figures out what happens and blames them for doing what they did, so he doesn't talk to them at all anymore even though they had a good relationship in the first half of the movie (this may not be true as I'm not 100% sure he actually figures out what they did). 
I think the final scene in the whole movie is the son having this famous exhibition of all his artworks (the majority of it is about his girlfriend that he lost when he was younger??) and his father coming to the exhibition (in secret?) and seeing the art and realising what his son has become.

Sounds like the Chinese drama Sunflower from 2005.

Relationship between father and son on a background of Maoist regime in China in the mid-20th century. The father, a painter by profession, interned in a labor camp for "re-education" and loses his ability to paint. he teaches his son to draw, but does so obsessively. The convoluted relationship between father and son that spread over the period of childhood, adolescence and maturity of the son are being resolved in a surprising and sensitive way.

The father secretly asks his son's girlfriend to get an abortion, and near the end, the son becomes an artist and his father visits his exhibition. Co-stars Joan Chen. Here's the poster and some pics:




I have seen this movie. A good one.

Sorry, I should've gone over the trailer. It had the right description, but was actually for a different film altogether (also called 'Sunflower', but from 2006). Now replaced with pics.
